# How to configure Horizon response _links.href values to use https?

Tags: horizon

I am running Stellar core and Horizon behind an Nginx reverse proxy and encountering issues with the `_link.href` output by Horizon. The SSL is terminated at nginx, with the connection to Horizon non-SSL.

The Horizon API is accessed via `https://xxx-test.example.com` but the output by Horizon `_links` is always of the form `http://xxx-test.example.com/accounts` (ie non HTTPS).

I cant seem to find a definitive resource in the docs for how to modify the output to be `https` (or even change the base url) for all links. I see from the public Stellar testnet, that all of the `_links.href` values are `https`, so I know it is possible but just unsure how.

Is the output URL protocol dynamic based on the incoming protocol? Is there a config I can use to override?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set the `X-Forwarded-Proto: https` header in your proxy.

[how to nginx](https://serverfault.com/questions/515957/how-to-have-nginx-forward-the-http-x-forwarded-proto-header)

or haproxy:

```
backend ...    
    http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Proto https
```

Comment: This appears to fix the issue for me.

To confirm: there is no config or override I can set with Horizon in order to set the base URL and protocol and avoid it being dynamic?

Comment: I remember how I wanted to use a different base URL with a sub path, but as far as I know the URL is constructed and not configurable at all.